# Ergodic action on quotient

Tags: ergodic-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

I am reading the [book](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063) "Introduction to arithmetic groups" by Dave Witte-Morris, and I am in Chpater 14 on ergodic theory. In particular I am stuck on exercise 14.2#16 which reads;

Assume $\Gamma$ is an irreducible lattice, and let $H$ be a closed, non-comapct subgroup of $G$. Show, for a.e. $x\in G/\Gamma$, that $Hx$ is dense in $G/\Gamma$.

I know from previous work that in this setting the action of $H$ on the quotient $G/\Gamma$ is ergodic, (and in fact the action of $\Gamma$ on $G/H$ is also ergodic), so my thought was to consider the indicator function $\chi$ of $\overline{Hx}$ for some $x\in G/\Gamma$.

Then $\chi:G/\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$ is an $H$-invariant measurable function, hence is essentially constant by ergodicity. Since $\chi$ only takes two values we have that either $\chi=1$ or $\chi=0$.

However both cases seem like they can happen so I don't know how to conclude that $\overline{Hx}=G/\Gamma$ from here.

Also I am wondering how you prove that this holds for a.e. $x\in G/\Gamma$ rather than all such $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{U_n\}_n$ be a countable base (of open sets). Then, $Hx$ is dense if and only if for each $n$, $x \in HU_n$. So it suffices to show $\cap_n HU_n$ has measure $1$, and so it suffices to show each $HU_n$ has measure $1$. But $H(HU_n) = HU_n$, so by ergodicity, the measure of $HU_n$ is $0$ or $1$, so it's $1$.

Comment: Can you explain the last line of reasoning a little more?

Comment: @user551642 last line? im on phone. what *exactly* do you not understand?

Comment: How can you conclude that the measure of $HU_{n}$ is not $0$?

Comment: @user551642 don't all non-empty open sets have positive measure? (note measure of $HU_n$ is equal to measure of $U_n$)

Comment: Wow, you're right, thanks.